# Java + OpenCV SVM Training Error

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to train a set of images to generate a training file and then identify some objects in images, separated set a positive and a negative set it up can train.

The problem occurs when I do the test with a file that was already trained, because it returns an error saying that the size of the input file is different from the size of the training sample. But that does not make sense, because the same image has already been trained.

```
public class Training{

protected static final String PATH_POSITIVE = "data/positivo/";
protected static final String PATH_NEGATIVE = "data/negativo/";
protected static final String XML = "data/test.xml";
protected static final String FILE_TEST = "data/positivo/1.jpg";

static {
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
}

protected static Mat getMat( Mat img ) {
    Mat timg = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor( img, timg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    timg = timg.reshape( 1, timg.width() * timg.height() );
    timg.convertTo( timg, CvType.CV_32FC1 );
    return timg;
}

public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

    Mat classes = new Mat();
    Mat trainingData = new Mat();

    Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
    Mat trainingLabels = new Mat();

    CvSVM clasificador;

    for ( File file : new File( PATH_POSITIVE ).listFiles() ) {
        Mat img = Highgui.imread( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        trainingImages.push_back( getMat( img ) );
        trainingLabels.push_back( Mat.ones( new Size( 1, img.width() * img.height() ), CvType.CV_32FC1 ) );
    }

    for ( File file : new File( PATH_NEGATIVE ).listFiles() ) {
        Mat img = Highgui.imread( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        trainingImages.push_back( getMat( img ) );
        trainingLabels.push_back( Mat.zeros( new Size( 1, img.width() * img.height() ), CvType.CV_32FC1 ) );
    }

    trainingImages.copyTo( trainingData );
    trainingData.convertTo( trainingData, CvType.CV_32FC1 );
    trainingLabels.copyTo( classes );

    CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
    params.set_kernel_type( CvSVM.LINEAR );
    params.set_svm_type( CvSVM.C_SVC );
    params.set_gamma( 3 );

    clasificador = new CvSVM( trainingData, classes, new Mat(), new Mat(), params );
    clasificador.train( trainingData, classes );
    clasificador.save( XML );

    //Finished the part of the training will run the test with any file

    clasificador = new CvSVM();
    clasificador.load( new File( XML ).getAbsolutePath() );
    Mat timg = getMat( Highgui.imread( new File( FILE_TEST ).getAbsolutePath() ) );
    timg = timg.reshape( 1, timg.width() * timg.height() );
    timg.convertTo( timg, CvType.CV_32FC1 );

    //Here the error occurs
    //Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:1114: error: (-209) The sample size is different from what has been used for training in function cvPreparePredictData
    System.out.println( clasificador.predict( timg ) );

}

}
```

I am using Java 8 and OpenCV 2.4.10

Comment: you have to use getMat() for your prediction image, too. and ofc. your test-img needs to have same size, than your train images

Comment: also, your labels look flawed. push_back() a single (**integer**) number per train image, not a (float)Mat

Comment: thanks for the help, I really had forgotten the getMat () for testing, I made this alteration, and removed the (float) the ConvertTo (), but now I have another little problem, on the same line
    `Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:1114: error: (-209) The sample size is different from what has been used for training in function cvPreparePredictData`

Comment: I believe the problem is when I create the new Size ()
 `new Size( 1, img.width() * img.height() )`

Comment: I updated the code of the issue with changes made

Comment: thank you, as the help of berak, I decided to make some changes and it worked successfully, thank you

Comment: I wonder if there is any way I train a cascade model using java?

Comment: Very usefull information, brow-joe. Thanks for that.I just wanted to ask which information you give to train the positives and the negatives?You are using a list of files. What are those files. Like in this line:"Mat img = getMat( file.getAbsolutePath() )"?Are those just random pictures you classified first in two categories?Or do are those MAT with Feature Points which you create with SIFT or SURF for example?Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass the folder where the training files are and the folder where the test files are, it will get the image files straight from the folder

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments given by @berak, I decided to make some changes to my original code. The result is the following code and it is working for me:

```
public class Training{

protected static final String PATH_POSITIVE = "data/positivo/";
protected static final String PATH_NEGATIVE = "data/negativo/";
protected static final String XML = "data/test.xml";
protected static final String FILE_TEST = "data/negativo/1.jpg";

private static Mat trainingImages;
private static Mat trainingLabels;
private static Mat trainingData;
private static Mat classes;
private static CvSVM clasificador;

static {
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
    trainingImages = new Mat();
    trainingLabels = new Mat();
    trainingData = new Mat();
    classes = new Mat();
}

public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
    trainPositive();
    trainNegative();
    train();
    test();
}

protected static void test() {
    Mat in = Highgui.imread( new File( FILE_TEST ).getAbsolutePath(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    clasificador.load( new File( XML ).getAbsolutePath() );
    System.out.println( clasificador );
    Mat out = new Mat();
    in.convertTo( out, CvType.CV_32FC1 );
    out = out.reshape( 1, 1 );
    System.out.println( out );
    System.out.println( clasificador.predict( out ) );
}

protected static void train() {
    trainingImages.copyTo( trainingData );
    trainingData.convertTo( trainingData, CvType.CV_32FC1 );
    trainingLabels.copyTo( classes );
    CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
    params.set_kernel_type( CvSVM.LINEAR );
    clasificador = new CvSVM( trainingData, classes, new Mat(), new Mat(), params );
    clasificador.save( XML );
}

protected static void trainPositive() {
    for ( File file : new File( PATH_POSITIVE ).listFiles() ) {
        Mat img = getMat( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        trainingImages.push_back( img.reshape( 1, 1 ) );
        trainingLabels.push_back( Mat.ones( new Size( 1, 1 ), CvType.CV_32FC1 ) );
    }
}

protected static void trainNegative() {
    for ( File file : new File( PATH_NEGATIVE ).listFiles() ) {
        Mat img = getMat( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        trainingImages.push_back( img.reshape( 1, 1 ) );
        trainingLabels.push_back( Mat.zeros( new Size( 1, 1 ), CvType.CV_32FC1 ) );
    }
}

protected static Mat getMat( String path ) {
    Mat img = new Mat();
    Mat con = Highgui.imread( path, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    con.convertTo( img, CvType.CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0 );
    return img;
}

}
```